# regexp or algorithm ideas for finding subsets in data for given multiple input sets

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, set, pattern-matching

`Data-to-look-in`, treated as a string of two digit decimals :
`050607030405010602091000080403021519227701080211130608090001141313121105040605020008070705`

Input sets, treated as a string of two digit decimals:
(a) `050607` 
and 
(b) `080211`

What I want :

Location of any "substring" in given order of input set (b) (`08, 02, 11, 0802, 0811, 0211`), IF it is closer than, say, 20 (10 two-digit)places from any input set (a), in given order (`05, 06, 07, 0506, 0507, 0607`), in `Data-to-look-in`.

There could be more input data sets, but for now, lets start with only two.

If this is not optimal for regular expressions, could You suggest the way I should deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm for finding in linear time locations of "substrings"  of input set in "Data-to-look-in" string.